# Proxy connection while browser is running

Tags: firefox, google-chrome, internet-explorer, proxy

I made an application that changes in registry value of two keys:
`Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings\ProxyServer` to

`ftp=10.8.0.1:808;http=10.8.0.1:808;https=10.8.0.1:808;socks=10.8.0.1:1080`

and

`Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings\ProxyEnable` to

`True`

It works on Firefox. I suppose that FF checks settings in registry every time it loads the page.

While IE is opened it prevents all registry changes in Internet Settings. Chrome needs restart or opening the `Proxy settings` to reload proxy information.

Is there a way to force reload proxy settings of IE and Chrome without restarting those applications?

Comment: Why don't you just change it in internet options and then run `netsh winhttp import proxy source=ie` in elevated cmd?

Comment: It doesn't change anything